# Entity Framework Core - Cannot Add First Migration

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create my first migration of an ASP.Net Core project I am developing in Visual Studio 2015. My Solution only has the one Project. My `project.json` file resides in the root of my Project folder.

I right-click on the Project and select 'Open command line > default' and enter the following:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialDatabase
```

The command line returns:

```
No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.
```

I have tried all different versions of EntityFrameworkCore and Tools. My `project.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.2" 
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.0-msbuild3-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-msbuild3-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-msbuild3-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-msbuild3-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Any advice would be extremely welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Point to the directory which has project.json and execute the command. I think you are in parent folder (one level up)currently.

Comment: Try this for us: in VS, open the Package Manager Console (if you dont see it, go to `View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console`).  In the PMC, call `Add-Migration {YourMigrationNameHere}`.

Comment: I think that using add-migration in the package manager has been deprecated now.

Answer (score 5):

```
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-msbuild3-final"
}
```

Version `1.0.0-msbuild3-final` only works with the new, MSBuild-based projects (not `project.json`). Use version `1.0.0-preview3-final` instead.

Comment: Good advice @bricelam. By chance, last night I tried using the following combination: `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.2"`, `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final"`, `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"`, `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-msbuild3-final"` and it worked. As a developer new to ASP.Net Core it's very difficult to find the right combination of packages which work together in harmony. Should I try `1.0.0-preview3-final`?

Comment: The tooling story has been a bit chaotic with the switch from `project.json` to MSBuild. When the tools finally RTM (with VS 2017), the story for EF at least will be to make sure all the major and minor version numbers alight (e.g. either 1.0 or 1.1, but not mixed) There are efforts going on to simplify how you get a single, coherent set of .NET Core packages...

Comment: Good to know. Like many, I'm sure, I look forward to it settling down.

Comment: if this is the answer then you can accept it no? @TDC

Comment: I would, but @bricelam suggested I use version `1.0.0-preview3-final` and I found that by using `1.0.0-preview2-final` everything worked. I don't actually know if the suggested version would fix my problem, much as I would like to mark it as correct. A moral dilemma!

Answer (score -1):

> **The dotnet-ef command has moved.**
>
> You will need to add a reference to
>   *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet* **AND**
>   *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design* to your dependencies in
>   project.json, then add *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet* to the tools section and you should be good to go.

Cited from: [http://errummwelluhh.blogspot.com](http://errummwelluhh.blogspot.com/2017/01/no-executable-found-matching-command.html).
I have also posted the same answer for the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991736/ef-core-error-no-project-was-found-change-the-current-working-directory-or-us/43879016#43879016).