# Unable to Publish to AWS Lambda from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: aws-lambda

I have installed VS 2015 SDK for AWS and .NetCore 1.0 as a prerequisite for deployment.

While trying to deploy from **Publish to AWS Lambda..** by right click on project, I am getting below error

"**No .NET project found in directory D:\SampleProjects\AWSServerless1\AWSLambda1\AWSLambda1 to build.**
"

[See Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVVjp.png)

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991736/ef-core-error-no-project-was-found-change-the-current-working-directory-or-us

Answer (score 0):

Are you using proper version aws lambda uploader or update it and test it

```
dotnet tool update -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
```

Comment: I have Amazon.Lambda.Tools v1.8.0 Installed. When I am trying to upgrade it to 3.1.2, it giving error "Package 'Amazon.Lambda.Tools 3.1.2' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project"